# Android Studio Key store

Tags: android, android-studio, android-developer-api

I have apps uploaded to Play Store. I am going to change my operating environment from Windows to Linux. So I will need the same keystore to update my app.

1. How can I use the same key store in Linux?
2. Why is this key store required?

Comment: Dude the keystore by default is that for Debug, for production apps dont lose the production keystore - you will not be able to upgrade your apps without that.

Answer (score 3):

You **have to** copy your keystore from platform to platform. It's highly recommanded as the doc say :

> Warning: Keep your keystore and private key in a safe and secure place, and ensure that you have secure backups of them. If you publish an app to Google Play and then lose the key with which you signed your app, you will not be able to publish any updates to your app, since you must always sign all versions of your app with the same key.
>   [(source)](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html)

Answer (score 0):

of course you can use it via the command line interface, you need to install the Android tools like Windows, it is required in order to authenticate your binary file on the Store, every binary, when deployed, needs an author.

Answer (score 0):

> Why is this key store required?

The key store is a way to identify you as the developer of a given package (i.e. android app). It prevent someone else to upload a totally different app to the play store and pretending it is an upgrade for your app.